# Tried to get zfs to replace faulty drive but ended up in this configuration mess. How to resolve?

Tags: zfs

Getting the issue below, Trying to replace ata-ST3000... drive but ended up with this configuration mess. How can I get the new drive to be inside raidz1-0? Help appreciated.

Thanks

```
# zpool status

  pool: home
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 00:09:59 with 0 errors on Sun Mar 12 00:34:00 2023
config:

    NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    home        ONLINE       0     0     0
      raidz1-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        sda6    ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdb6    ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors

  pool: zfshdd
 state: DEGRADED
status: One or more devices are faulted in response to persistent errors.
    Sufficient replicas exist for the pool to continue functioning in a
    degraded state.
action: Replace the faulted device, or use 'zpool clear' to mark the device
    repaired.
  scan: scrub repaired 260K in 5 days 10:37:43 with 0 errors on Fri Mar 17 12:01:45 2023
config:

    NAME                                          STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    zfshdd                                        DEGRADED     0     0     0
      raidz1-0                                    DEGRADED     0     0     0
        ata-ST3000VX010-2E3166_Z730QWCN           FAULTED     19     0     2  external device fault
        ata-WDC_WD30PURZ-85GU6Y0_WD-WCC4N1KAV0TD  ONLINE       0     0     0
      ata-WDC_WD30PURZ-85GU6Y0_WD-WCC4N7KVPT3T    ONLINE       0     0     0
```

Replacing faulty drive with new one but ended up with the configuration issue

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works. Read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to improve the quality of your question. Learn what an [on-topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) is. Then take a look to [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to see if some _on-topic questions_ are already asked.

Comment: This question is not [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Are you trying to make a RAID 5 (raidz) and add more drives in the future? If not, use mirror instead.